# Assign all file matches from a folder to a variable

Tags: bash, file, variables, pattern-matching

I would like to search for a simple text query (inside of a directory named "textfiles") and based on the matches, assign the results to a variable in `bash` (as an array or list).  This query should be case-insensitive, and the context is inside of a bash script (.sh file).  The names I'd hope to see in the array are simply the filenames, not the full paths.

**What I am trying:**

`myfiles=./textfiles/*text*.txt`

This matches all files that have the word `text` in them, but not the word `TEXT`.

I've also tried

`myfiles=(find textfiles -iname *text*)`

...and...

`myfiles=find textfiles -iname *text*`

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: I think the 'find' commands should work if you just put the *text* inside double quotes to keep bash from expanding the glob so that the * are passed down to find as is.

Comment: `myfiles=$(find textfiles -iname *text* 2>/dev/null)`.

Comment: Wait... Also just noticed you forgot to wrap them...  You probably want to wrap the find command in either $() or ''

Comment: @Roadowl I can never figure out when to use `/dev/null` or what that implies.  Do you have a link to this usage?  I think it prevents the script from crashing? -- off topic, I know

Comment: It prevents messages such as `find: ‘/home/me/Documents/old-system/var/log/samba/cores’: Permission denied` messages ending up in the output list. 2 is file descriptor 2, aka stderr. I.o.w. "route stderr to /dev/null", the black hole in your computer universe.

Comment: @Roadowl - I think this is working, although I just need the filenames, not the full paths.  Can you post this amendment as an answer?

Comment: @JustinB : Using `-iname *text*` would also match files containing the string _TEXT_, which the OP wants to have excluded.

Comment: @user1934428 no, I would like that case included. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myfiles=$(find textfiles -iname '*text*' -exec basename '{}' \; 2>/dev/null)
```

Note how `-exec` allows you to perform powerful operations on the files `find` finds. Maybe you do not even need the array after all, and can do what you need to do right there in the `-exec` argument.
And be aware that the `-exec` argument may be a script or other executable of your own making...

Comment: Do I need to include the `\;` to signal the end of the execution list or is this optional?

Comment: Yes, you do, or at least `find` needs it. You could use a plus ('+') if `basename(1)` accepted multiple filenames, but it doesn't.

Comment: also: how can I employ `-exec` to use this filename (or path) as an argument for another bash script?

Comment: Say you have a script called myscript with  `#!/bin/bash <newline> echo "$1"` then you just use -exec myscript '{}' \;  Be sure to make your script executable: `chmod 700 myscript`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# plain 
myfiles=($(find textfiles -iname *text*))
# if you write like below, you get the result in myflies as a single string
myfiles=$(find textfiles -iname *text*)
# if you want to assign all string as array then you write the following way
myfiles=(abc def ijk)
```

But this impose a problem, if there is space in your file name or directory name, it will give you incorrect result. Better solution would be

```
myfiles=()
while read -r fname; do 
  push myfiles $fname; 
done < <(find . -type f)
```

As @Roadowl suggested better alternative to be **xargs** can be a better alternative

There are more than one way to solve a problem.

Comment: Better solution would be to xargs, but I didn't want to complicate matters too sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said in your posting explicitly that you want to have files containing `text`, but not `TEXT`, you can *not* do a case-insensitive search, but have to be case-sensitive:

```
myfiles=($(find -name '*text*' 2>/dev/null))
```

However, this would also return a file named `x.text.y.TEXT.z`. If you want to exclude this file (since you consider exclusion of `TEXT` more important than inclusion of `text`), you can do a

```
myfiles=($(find -name '*text*' '!' -name '*TEXT*' 2>/dev/null))
```

Comment: apologies if my post was unclear, but I think you might have misinterpreted it - I was saying that in my example, `text` is matched, and not `TEXT`, and that this is undesireable.  ;)